# Why Isn't ConfirmImpact Working as Expected Here?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I created Test-ConfirmImpact.ps1 as so:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact="High")]
Param (
    $Test = 1
)

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\Test"
```

Observe the following:

```
PS > $ConfirmPreference
High
PS > .\Test-ConfirmImpact.ps1


Directory: \\afgfile02\users\radams\scripts\PowerShell


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         8/14/2013  12:34 PM            Test


PS > $ConfirmPreference = "Medium"
PS > Remove-Item ".\Test"

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Remove Directory" on Target ".\Test".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
PS > .\Test-ConfirmImpact.ps1

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Create directory" on Target "Destination: \.Test".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

So, why do I not receive a confirmation prompt in the first case? I would expect that if my confirm preference is "high" then an event with an impact of "high" ought to trigger a confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[CmdletBinding(ConfirmImpact="High")` only tells your script the behaviour to use when you use the `ShouldProcess` method. It does NOT set the ConfirmPreference.

The logic is a little weird.

> The call to the ShouldProcess method displays a confirmation prompt only when the ConfirmImpact argument is equal to or greater than the value of the $ConfirmPreference preference variable.

ConfirmImpact is an enum, where High=3, Medium=2, Low=1, None=0

New-Item on an item that doesn't exist has a Confirm of Med(2), 2 < High(3), so no prompt.

When you set it to Medium again, 2 -eq 2, it prompts.

Remove-Item has a default impact of High(3) since it results in data loss, 3 -ge (any confirm preference), so it always prompts.

For more information on how to handle ShouldProcess and ConfirmImpact, see http://iheartpowershell.blogspot.co.za/2013/05/powershell-supportsshouldprocess-worst.html